# supress generatenewblock output

Tags: command-line, bash

I am issuing a command as follows:

```
rando-cli generate 1 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

yet still I see output such as

```
2020-06-19T17:54:29Z [default wallet] keypool reserve 17
2020-06-19T17:54:29Z CreateNewBlock(): block weight: 944 txs: 0 fees: 0 sigops 400
2020-06-19T17:54:30Z CreateNewBlock(): block weight: 944 txs: 0 fees: 0 sigops 400
2020-06-19T17:54:30Z CreateNewBlock(): block weight: 944 txs: 0 fees: 0 sigops 400
```

I have also tried

```
ranod-cli generate 1 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

How can I suppress this output?

Comment: is that from some log file or console, normally you do `&>/dev/null` to supress all outputs

Comment: it is whats displayed in console and I cannot get it to stop displaying. Sending to `/dev/null` is not working no matter how i try it.

Answer (score 2):

```
rando-cli generate 1
```

Above is an RCP command and the RCP command doesn't output anything, it is the RPC server that displays the output. So I had to suppress the error messages from the daemon not the command.

```
randod > /dev/null 2>&1
```